# Why is there a smiley face and white space on the mobile version of my site?

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, responsive-design

Here's the site:
**https://BlendBee.com**

On my Android (Samsung Galaxy S5) in the Chrome app, there's a few issues:

1. White space on the right-side (you can drag the screen to the right and there's a white bar)
2. White space at the bottom (see screenshot)
3. A smiley face at the bottom (see screenshot)

Any ideas how to fix these?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For white spacing, you need to add the following `css` for `responsive` view

```
.js #mobile-menu{
  margin-right: 0;
  width: auto;
}
```

Also for bottom smiley `image`, you need to find and remove following code from `HTML`. Its came in your desktop view also. Once you removed that `image` your bottom spacing issue will also resolved.

```
https://pixel.wp.com/g.gif?host=blendbee.com&rand=0.3194744260981679&v=ext&j=1%3A3.0.2&blog=68911511&post=4473&tz=-7&ref=http%3A//stackoverflow.com/questions/24765633/why-is-there-a-smiley-face-and-white-space-on-the-mobile-version-of-my-site
```

Comment: Thanks!  That did the trick.  I also disabled the WordPress stats module in JetPack to remove that smiley face.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the first problem, but there is a white row and a smiley face in the desktop version of your website also. Found this line in `inspect element` of `chrome`:

```
<img id="wpstats" src="https://stats.wordpress.com/g.gif?host=blendbee.com&amp;rand=0.8257986863609403&amp;v=ext&amp;j=1%3A3.0.2&amp;blog=68911511&amp;post=4473&amp;tz=-7&amp;ref=http%3A//stackoverflow.com/questions/24765633/why-is-there-a-smiley-face-and-white-space-on-the-mobile-version-of-my-site" alt="">
```

This line only appears in the `inspect element` but is not in the `View Source`, so it must be generated by one of the client-side scripts you have included. Looking at the `src` attribute of this smiley face, it is from `https://stats.wordpress.com/g.gif` and also contains a bunch of query string parameters. (host, ref, blog, etc.) Add these clues to the id of the image (`"wpstats"`), my guess is that it is one of the WordPress tracker GIFs that is introduced by one of the WordPress JavaScript scripts.

Hope this helps you :)

---

Edit:
Found the source of the gif in this script:

```
<script src="https://stats.wordpress.com/e-201429.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In the first line:

```
function st_go(a){var i,u=document.location.protocol+'//stats.wordpress.com/g.gif?host='+escape(document.location.host)+'&rand='+Math.random();for(i in a){u=u+'&'+i+'='+escape(a[i]);}u=u+'&ref='+escape(document.referrer);document.open();document.write("<img id=\"wpstats\" src=\""+u+"\" alt=\"\" />");document.close();}
```

You can make a local copy of this file (copy-and-paste to your html) and remove the `document.write()` part and you should be all set.

Comment: Nice find!  I disabled the WordPress Stats module in JetPack and that removed the tracking pixel:  /wp-admin/admin.php?page=jetpack_modules